# entity framework 6 system.outofmemoryexception

Tags: entity-framework, stored-procedures, entity-framework-6

I keep getting a system.outofmemoryexception:

> Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown. 
>   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.set_Capacity(Int32 value) 
>   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.EnsureCapacity(Int32 min) 
>   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.Add(T item) 
>   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection) 
>   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source) 
>   at CIGDataLibrary.Archive.ArchiveCycleData(String applicationName) 
>   in c:!TFS\SCCSoftware\Commercial\CIG\Wagering\CIGDataLibrary\files\Archive.cs:line 571

Code at line 571:

```
List<Guid?> cycleData = Queries.Current.GetCycleDataArchiveList();
```

The method:

```
public static List<Guid?> GetCycleDataArchiveList()
{
    using (var dbContext = new CIGDataModels.CIGDBStoredProcModels())
    {
        return dbContext.usp_arch_GetCycleData().ToList();
    }
}
```

And the meat of the stored procedure:

```
SELECT TOP 1000 gpCycleData_Id FROM CIGDB.dbo.cig_Cycle_gpCycleData
WHERE [TimeStamp] < DATEADD(HH, 3, DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE())))
ORDER BY [TimeStamp]
```

Any thoughts on why this is occurring?  It should be returning 1000 records (just a list of GUIDs) so shouldn't be throwing a fit, right?  I've taken the SP down to TOP 1 but still results in same error.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with this code. Does it still error if you replace the call the the stored procedure with `return new List<Guid?> { new Guid() };`

Comment: Yes, works fine.  I should also add that it works just fine here on my development machine.  It throws the error on the production machine.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that the production database has `TOP 1` or `TOP 1000` in the stored proc?

Comment: Yes, it usually had ran just fine with TOP 1000, and had been running with it just fine for months.  But a week and a half ago, we started getting this error.  I reduced it to TOP 1 to test and still got same error.

Comment: Then I don't understand. The error message you show is essentially saying there are too many items in the list as it's trying to set the capacity to some value too large. See [list capacity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y52x03h2(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: how about trying to alter the stored procedure with `select NEWID() gpCycleData_Id` ?

Comment: @Yuliam - Wouldn't that create a new id for the record?  I'm trying to capture a list of existing Id's for later archiving by another process.

Comment: I think you need to trace exactly what the stored procedure is doing before you go modifying it. First confirm the stored proc is being called and that there are no triggers or anything else like that. Perhaps run the SQL manually to see how many rows you are getting.

Comment: try with what davidg suggested first, use sql profiler or enable logging on the query..

Comment: Unfortunately, I've done that and the stored procedure does exactly as it's supposed to.  It returns 1000 or 1 records as the TOP designates.  There are no triggers in the database that I'm aware of (I would have been the one to put them in if there was).

Comment: Then I suggest SQL Profiler. One off-the-wall suggestion is: might there be another stored proc with the same name but in a different schema?

Comment: No, they are all unique.  CIGDBStoredProcModels does have all my stored procs, but that SP is the only one called in this instance.

Answer (score 0):

Your production database is returning too many rows. It's likely missing the `TOP n` clause within the stored procedure, hence it's returning so much data that your application is running out of memory.

As you say you have edited the stored proc to only return a single row and it's still causing an error, there must be another factor.

Assuming that there's nothing more to the procedure than you have posted, some possible reasons:

1. A trigger is affecting the output in some way.
2. Entity framework is calling a different procedure. Check the content of your model to determine the correct procedure is being called.
3. Another procedure exists in a different schema. For example, your app logs into the database with username `myApp` and when it calls `MyProc` it's resolving to `myApp.MyProc` instead of `dbo.MyProc`.

Comment: Just verified it is calling dbo.usp_arch_GetCycleData.  Sql Profiler is showing the call to exec [dbo].[usp_arch_GetCycleData] but it doesn't show what it is returning.

Comment: Take the query from Profiler and paste it into a new query window, run it and see what the output is. Check both the result set and the messages window.

Comment: could you change this `return dbContext.usp_arch_GetCycleData().ToList();` into `var items = dbContext.usp_arch_GetCycleData().ToList();` and `return items;` then put a breakpoint on `return items;` will it still throw exception?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured out the issue and it has run as expected.

Contrary to the exception's stack trace, the error was on line 572, not 571.
That line was

```
List<Guid> arch_gpCycle = dbarchContext.cig_Cycle_gpCycleData.Select(s => s.gpCycleData_Id).ToList();
```

And that resulted in the system.outofmemoryexception.  I have since changed it to a compiled query that returns a list of Guids and it has run successfully.

Comment: Seriously, after all that effort and you gave us the wrong information?